# C#, integer overflow

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to programming. Doing a factorial problem, I'm getting back the incorrect values. I understand it's because they're too large, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
using System;

namespace Factorial
{
    class Program
    {
        public static long factoring(int n)
        {
            if (n == 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            return n * factoring(n - 1);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int lines, value;
            lines = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
            {
                value = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine(factoring(value));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You could use BigInteger: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should use `checked` keyword to explicitly enable overflow checking for integral-type arithmetic  in order to avoid overflow, as detailed in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx . In you case, like:

```
return checked(n * factoring(n - 1));
```

On overflow Function will throw exception instead of returning the wrong number. In case you need to operate with bigger Integer numbers, use `Int64` or `Decimal` Type. In general, Integer factorial of big numbers (>20) is problematic, though approximate solutions exist. Rgds,

Comment: That will detect the problem, but not fix it.